# Messaging Services added to existing A2P Campaign but SMS texts still failing

Tags: sms, activecampaign

On Friday, my ORG was caught off guard by the new and gradual blocking of phone numbers not associated with A2P Campaigns. For a new A2P, Twilio states that the vetting can take up to three weeks. I found an old and already vettted and Approved A2P Campaign and assigned every Production phone number that was associated with other messaging services to that campaign. Even after doing that, messages are still failing to deliver. Basically, texting is completely shut down for all my Agents and there is no reason they should fail as they are assigned to a Vetted A2P Campaign.

Found an old exisiting A2P Campaign and registered all messaging services and phone numbers to it. I expected the messages would start showing up as delivered in Logs, but they are not.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a programming problem to me, so it's off-topic here. You may have to check with Twilio support. See also [ask].